# Action Client Not Picking Up Messages from Action Server

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, actionlib, action-server, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm not sure what I've missed here. Simply I have followed the action server/client tutorials and I've extended my own messages so that I can determine if the robot has or has not docked successfully.

I can see that the server is publishing the messages correctly however I must be missing something on the client side because despite setting up the callbacks when sendGoal is called and I can see that the callback is indeed called the message from the server isn't coming through.

Trying to show by example:

Server outputs:

```
[INFO] [1538084823.620614089]: DockDrive::processBumpChargeEvent 
[INFO] [1538084823.620698260]: Docked DONE! [ INFO] [1538084823.620843878]:[/fibonacci]: Arrived on docking station successfully.
```

Running

rostopic echo /fibonacci/result shows:

```
status:
  goal_id:
    stamp:
      secs: 1538084809
      nsecs: 414171018
    id: "/test_fibonacci-1-1538084809.414171018"
  status: 3
  text: ''
result:
  text: "Arrived on docking station successfully."
  state: "DONE"
```

Note Result message Text and State are set

On the Client side "Answer" is just a "?". It should read the text part of the result above i.e. "Arrived on docking station successfully."

```
[ INFO] [1538084809.141452693]: Waiting for action server to start.
[ INFO] [1538084809.414082459]: Action server started, sending goal.
[ INFO] [1538084809.415720796]: Goal just went active
[ INFO] [1538084823.621925341]: Finished in state [SUCCEEDED]
**[ INFO] [1538084823.622168467]: Answer: ?**
[ INFO] [1538084823.622424793]: Docked OK!
[ INFO] [1538084823.622538900]: Action finished: SUCCEEDED
```

The relevant parts of the Client side code:

Callback defined as:

```
void doneCb(const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState& state,
            const AutoDockingResultConstPtr& result)
{
    ROS_INFO("Finished in state [%s]", state.toString().c_str());
    ROS_INFO("Answer: %s", result->text);
}
```

And the main body of the code is:

```
void spinThread()
{
  ros::spin();
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_fibonacci");

  // create the action client
  // true causes the client to spin it's own thread
  actionlib::SimpleActionClient<mxnet_actionlib::AutoDockingAction> ac("fibonacci", true);
  boost::thread spin_thread(&spinThread);

  ROS_INFO("Waiting for action server to start.");
  // wait for the action server to start
  ac.waitForServer(); //will wait for infinite time

  ROS_INFO("Action server started, sending goal.");
  // send a goal to the action
  mxnet_actionlib::AutoDockingGoal goal;

  // Need to register for feedback
  ac.sendGoal(goal, &doneCb, &activeCb, &feedbackCb);

  //wait for the action to return
  bool finished_before_timeout = ac.waitForResult();
  actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState state = ac.getState();

  if (state == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::LOST)
  {
    ROS_INFO("Docking Lost - Attempting Redocking");
  }
  else if (state == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED)
  {
     ROS_INFO("Docked OK!");
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_INFO("Docking Failed!");
  }

  if (finished_before_timeout)
  {
    actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState state = ac.getState();
    ROS_INFO("Action finished: %s",state.toString().c_str());
  }
  else
    ROS_INFO("Action did not finish before the time out.");

  return 0;
}
```

If someone can see what I've missed here I'd appreciate it.

Many Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304432/action-client-not-picking-up-messages-from-action-server/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2018-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved.

I forgot to add ".c_str()" e.g.

ROS_INFO("Answer: %s", result->text); should read

ROS_INFO("Answer: %s", result->text.c_str());

To the end of the string expansion....ugh #Simples #CodeBlind

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2018-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1